# What is the link above the title of some YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

On the YouTube website, the video title is under the video player. Above the title, there is sometimes a link with some text. Example from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWTVppEigTQ) video (`LAUREL`):
[image: xWTVppEigTQ]

Clicking the link initiates an YouTube search for the text in the link.

What is this link for and how to add one to a video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the text labeling part of a [Series](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7340626?vid=0-1085109387077-1521947153033) [Playlist](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6084043?hl=en) [image: Series Episode Label Example: Buzzfeed Unsolved - True Crime S1E12 The Strange Disappearance of D.B. Cooper] or a video on Trending[image: #3 On Trending: Every Pixar Movie Reviewed in 10 Words or Less! by JelloApocalypse]. They all have similar HTML: all are a `yt-simple-endpoint` contained within a `super-title`. <s>Maybe this is a bug with the indended uses of super-titles.</s>

EDIT: [This Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/63w7ve/how_do_i_split_up_my_playlist_into_seasons_and/) helped me find this info

EDIT 2: This is a geotag for Laurel, Maryland. Confirmed by the user who posted the video. Clicking on the `Laurel` tag brings up other videos with the same geotag.[image: Youtube Comment Section. Becket Clark: what is LAUREL. Luke Justin Roberts: It’s the geo tag for this video. It’s a little weird how it puts it above the title]

Comment: Ah, seems like it's used for many things. I tried clicking the `Filter` button on the search page after clicking `LAUREL` and it showed bolded **Location** under Features with an `x` next to it. Clicking the `x` searched for `Laurel` without the geotag.

Comment: FWIW: A series and a series playlist are different things. The former puts the label above the title and as of writing this is in a closed beta, the latter makes other videos in the playlist more likely to show up as "next up" if you are on the regular watch page and is available for anyone. FWIW2: HC article for the location thingy is at https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7638112